# git push via ssh to ubuntu vm not working but i am able to ssh to the same ubuntu

Tags: git

I have setup of ubuntu Guest VM on Virtualbox on mac host.

i have setup the ubuntu as server with the [help](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

created ssh key and put the public key on the ubuntu and i am able to ssh

i have added remote repo like this

`git remote add origin ssh://git@192.168.1.8:/var/opt/repo-demo.git`

but i am not able do a git push to the ubuntu vm.

However I am able to login via ssh as git user like `ssh git@192.168.1.8`

tried with `git push --verbose` doesn`t help. Can someone help me on this

Comment: Please provide the error that you get when you try a git push.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have mixed the two possible syntaxes (scp and url) for git over ssh. The following scp style should work.

```
git remote add origin git@192.168.1.8:/var/opt/repo-demo.git
```

The following URL style should also work.

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@192.168.1.8/var/opt/repo-demo.git
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but Its asking for password for git, but i have added my public key in authorized_keys file, So it should not ask for the password rather it should authenticate via the keys. why its not happening.

Comment: Check permissions on your authorized keys file and .ssh directory.  Make sure they are 600 and 700 respectively.